# PHP mail() load image to email without having to click "Load all images"

Tags: php, image, email, html-email, email-attachments

When I create an email and send an image in the body of the email, most email clients make you click "Load all images" I want this to load automatically like a regular email would from any other company. Like an html email. This image is hosted on an external website, and is around 500kb-1.5mb and around 900x1200 size. How can I accomplish this? Is it just a header issue?

```
$from = "";
$headers = "From:" . $from ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$to = "";
$subject =  "";
$subject = html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


    $message = '<html><head>';
    $message .='</head><body>';
    $message .='<img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/2qjkb2u.jpg"/>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: If you figure this out, please be sure to post it everywhere. You'll be hailed as a hero by spammers everywhere, and hunted down and tortured to death by everyone who's been forced to watch umpteen boner pills ads being pushed by russian brides.

Comment: While you can never guarantee that all email clients will load your images by default, you may be able to get a higher percentage of them to load images as embedded resources in the message as opposed to external resources on the web.  The downside is that each message would individually contain the image data, so you'd want to keep the images small and light.

Comment: @MarcB I'm sure it can done. Not that I'd do it and even start looking for a way, but it has happened to me a few times where an email containing images automatically appeared, mostly in Yahoo. So I'm sure someone figured a way going through Javascript. Plus, I'm sure I didn't give it permission to "display images".

Comment: @fred: nope. but they CAN embed the images as data uris, at the cost of bloating the email's size.

Comment: @MarcB probably the way they're doing it.

Comment: @david: loading embedded images will generally always work. the image is already there. what mail clients won't do is go fetch an image/resource from an EXTERNAL source, as that's where the privacy leaks occur (e.g. web bugs).

Comment: @MarcB: Generally, but still not guaranteed.  Some (many?) email clients would still allow globally disabling images without explicit user action for the very reason you pointed out (images of boner pill ads, or worse).  If the OP is looking for control over the output, it's the same 80/20, 90/10, 95/5, etc. rules that apply in any web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enforce this as it is not within your control. Email clients don't load images by default to protect the privacy of their users. (Spammers can track email addresses using images. The image is loaded via a server side script which confirms the email was received and viewed. Then spammers know the email address is valid and active). That's why it takes an active action by the user to actually view the images in the email.